# Cordova run browser on Internet Explorer or Microsoft Edge fails

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, angular6, phonegap, apache-cordova

I created a Cordova project and integrated it with Angular 6, there after added browser platform using command Cordova Platform Add Browser , after performing ng build and hosting the angular output with Cordova, using command Cordova Run browser, it works fine in chrome browser , however for Internet Explorer or Microsoft Edge it fails to render the page and throws below error message

```
System.ArgumentNullException: No message was deserialized prior to calling the DispatchChannelSink.

Parameter name: requestMsg

   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.DispatchChannelSink.ProcessMessage(IServerChannelSinkStack sinkStack, IMessage requestMsg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream, IMessage& responseMsg, ITransportHeaders& responseHeaders, Stream& responseStream)

   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.BinaryServerFormatterSink.ProcessMessage(IServerChannelSinkStack sinkStack, IMessage requestMsg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream, IMessage& responseMsg, ITransportHeaders& responseHeaders, Stream& responseStream)

   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.SoapServerFormatterSink.ProcessMessage(IServerChannelSinkStack sinkStack, IMessage requestMsg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream, IMessage& responseMsg, ITransportHeaders& responseHeaders, Stream& responseStream)

   at System.Runtime.Remoting.MetadataServices.SdlChannelSink.ProcessMessage(IServerChannelSinkStack sinkStack, IMessage requestMsg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream, IMessage& responseMsg, ITransportHeaders& responseHeaders, Stream& responseStream)

   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Http.HttpServerTransportSink.ServiceRequest(Object state)

   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.SocketHandler.ProcessRequestNow()
```

We tried adding missing polyfills and shims and meta http-equiv like below in index.html

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.5.13/es5-sham.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

When we perform cordova run browser and Launch the hosted angular website in Internet Explorer or Microsoft Edge, it should work in a similar way as in chrome browser.

Comment: Only error message will not help to find the cause for the issue. can you provide us the detailed steps with your sample code? Also inform us which documentation you are referring to executing your code. We will try to check it and try to produce the issue.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I have edited the question, provided more details about the problem

Comment: For testing purpose, can you try to create an empty new project and try to test it with IE and Edge? It may help to get the idea whether there is any configuration related issue or it is a coding related issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying for a day, found that the default port 8000 was in use, hence had to change in run.js found at path "platforms\browser\cordova\" 
with the following values

```
args.port = args.port || 8100;
args.target = args.target || "ie";//prior to this instead of "ie" it was "chrome"
```